# regsub and string trim works almost same?

Tags: string, tcl

I have used both commands `regsub` and `string trim` for removal of white spaces and desired characters.

Both can be used for same kind of task so far...(almost one or other way it worked well with me)

Is there any major or note-worthy point while using above syntax?

Has anyone came over any major benefit of using one instead of other for any particular example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all `string trim` only meant to remove only the leading and trailing chars. If suppose, that char resides in middle or other than leading or trailing position, then `string trim` will let it go as such. You can't use regular expressions in this too. Many advantages with `regsub`.

Also `string trim` will remove them as list of chars. Not as single whole string.

Comment: I am aware about `regsub` as *subsitution* ,My main concern was about trimming via `regsub`

Answer (score 2):

While `regsub` can do what `string trim` does, it's hardly a great use of the power of `regsub`. On the other hand, `string trim` is a simple command and does what it does and just does that. Thus one of the benefits of `string trim` is that it is easier to use *provided you want what it does*, and one of the benefits of `regsub` is that it can do very complicated things.

Because it is simpler, `string trim` is faster.

```
% set s "      example text      "
      example text      
% puts >>[string trim $s]<<
>>example text<<
% puts >>[regsub {^\s*(\S(?:.*\S)?)\s*$} $s {\1}]<<
>>example text<<
% time {string trim $s} 10000
0.662736 microseconds per iteration
% time {regsub {^\s*(\S(?:.*\S)?)\s*$} $s {\1}} 10000
2.6273805 microseconds per iteration
```

Timings are unscientific and unvalidated; just compare the relative speeds, OK? And that `string trim` is about 4 times faster than that `regsub` (which is the correct one for emulating what `string trim` does)…

Comment: Err, I think that `regsub {^\s*|\s*$} $s ""` is more suited for a trim via regsub, *if* you'd ever have/want to do it. That brings the time down to something around 0.9 ms :)

Comment: @Jerry: it's always a good idea to test code before suggesting it. Your invocation does not trim whitespace at both ends of the string.

Comment: @Hoodiecrow oh I forgot to put the -all switch here. I already tested it and that's how I got 0.9 ms

Comment: @Jerry: on my system, without the `-all` switch the trimming is significantly faster than Donal's `regsub` invocation, but doesn't trim both sides. With the `-all` switch, both sides are trimmed, but performance is the same or worse than Donal's solution. In both cases, `string trim` is a lot faster than either `regsub` solution.